# how to create from month Gtk.Calendar a week calendar and display the notes in each day in python

Tags: python, linux, gtk

I have created a calendar app with month and week view in python.
In month view,  I can write notes in each day, store them in a dictionary and save the dictionary in to disk so I can read it any time.

Now I am working on week view.I managed to display the week of the month regard the day I have picked from month view (the number of the week and the days, Monday to Sunday).In code,  I used `Gtk.Label` for the number of the week and the days of the week attached them in a `Gtk.Grid`. Beneath each day  I have attached a `Gtk.TextView` using a `for in` loop creating a list of `Gtk.TextView` where is being displayed the notes of each day from month view.Right now I have managed to display only one note each time I pick a day of a week.If I have multiple notes in different days can not display all of them.And here is my question.
Below is a snippet of code where the week calendar is updating(`def update_week_cal`).How to modify the code in loop part, so I can display all the notes in each week I have picked from month view?

```
    def update_week_cal(self, *args):
        year, month, day = self.calendar.get_date()
        month = month + 1
        today = datetime.date(year, month, day)
        self.page2.remove(self.label)
        self.label = Gtk.Label(str(today.isocalendar()[1]) + "η Εβδομάδα")
        self.page2.attach(self.label, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        dates = list([today + datetime.timedelta(days=i) for i in range(0 - today.weekday(), 7 - today.weekday())])
        j = 0
        for days in dates:
            self.labels[j].destroy()
            if days == today:
                self.labels[j] = Gtk.Label()
                self.labels[j].set_markup('<span font = "12" weight = "bold">{0}</span>'.format(days.strftime("%a ""%d/""%m")))
            else:
                self.labels[j] = Gtk.Label(days.strftime("%a ""%d/""%m"))
            self.page2.attach(self.labels[j], j, 2, 1, 1)
            self.page2.remove(self.textviews[j])
            self.textviews[j] = Gtk.TextView()
            self.textviews[j].set_editable(False)
            self.textviews[j].set_wrap_mode(Gtk.WrapMode.WORD_CHAR)
            self.page2.attach(self.textviews[j], j, 3, 1, 1)
            for i in range(7):
                try:
                    if self.text is not None and self.d[(year, month, day)]:
                        x = int(today.strftime("%w"))-1
                        self.textviews[x].get_buffer().set_text(self.text)
                except KeyError:
                    x = int(today.strftime("%w")) - 1
                    self.textviews[x].get_buffer().set_text(self.text)
                    print(i, j, x)

                except TypeError:
                    x = int(today.strftime("%w")) - 1
                    self.textviews[x].get_buffer().set_text(self.text)

            self.show_all()
            j = j + 1
```

Take into account that I have used the same `Gtk.TextBuffer` for month and week view.
`self.text` are the notes  from month view.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I managed to display  the notes according to date, changing  the way of thinking the problem and starting from beginning.The new code is been added at the end of the old one, subtracting this:

```
            for i in range(7):
                try:
                    if self.text is not None and self.d[(year, month, day)]:
                        x = int(today.strftime("%w"))-1
                        self.textviews[x].get_buffer().set_text(self.text)
                except KeyError:
                    x = int(today.strftime("%w")) - 1
                    self.textviews[x].get_buffer().set_text(self.text)
                    print(i, j, x)

                except TypeError:
                    x = int(today.strftime("%w")) - 1
                    self.textviews[x].get_buffer().set_text(self.text)
```

The answer to the problem is the below code:

```
list_of_dates = list(self.d.keys())
list_of_notes = list(self.d.values())
dictionary = dict(zip(list_of_dates, list_of_notes))
for key in dictionary.items():
    date = datetime.date(year=key[0][0], month=key[0][1]+1, day=key[0][2])
    week_of_day = str(date.isocalendar()[1])            
    day_of_week = int(date.strftime("%w"))-1          
    if week == week_of_day:
        self.textviews[day_of_week].get_buffer().set_text(key[1])
```